# Generate random char/digit

Tags: c++, random, char, digit

I`m trying to found fastest way to generate random digit/char array.

```
char *randomGet(int num) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    const char ab[37] = { "0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" };//Alphabet&Digit
    char *targ = new char[num];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        strcat(targ, ab[rand() % 38]);
    }
    return targ;
}
```

So far I've come up with this, but it does not work (argument of type char is incompatible with parameter of type const char *).
Help me find the best solution to my problem. Ty.

Comment: Stop trying to use `strcat`.

Comment: Start using std::string.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Yeah, that would also fix the off-by-one error in the memory allocation. :-)

Comment: Don't call `srand` anywhere but the beginning of `main` (unless you know what you're doing, which you don't if you're trying to call `srand` in a function supposed to return random results).

Comment: Better yet, use the random facilities that C++ provides, rather than the long-in-the-tooth srand and rand of the Standard C Library.

Comment: @melpomene, does not the use of strings affect the execution time of the code negatively?

Comment: @Eljay I've done it all my life that way. Well, I read, and will use modern functions.

Comment: @Danij Not as much as calling `strcat` in a loop.

Comment: @melpomene It is not planned that the loop be repeated more than 12 times :D

Comment: @Danij Then why do you care how fast it is? (Especially since you're using `new` and `strcat` already, which makes no sense in something that's supposed to be the "fastest way".)

Comment: Ok, where is my mistake now? :S http://prntscr.com/jyhbcc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcat()` takes a `char*` as input, but you are giving it a single `char` instead, thus the compiler error.

Also, the buffer that `strcat()` writes to must be null terminated, but your `targ` buffer is not null terminated initially, and you are not allocating enough space for a final null terminator anyway.

You don't need to use `strcat()` at all. Since you are looping anyway, just use the loop counter as the index where to write in the buffer:

Also, you are using the wrong integer value when modulo the return value of `rand()`.  You are producing a random index that *may* go out of bounds of your `ab[]` array.

Try this instead:

```
char *randomGet(int num)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    static const char ab[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //Alphabet&Digit
    char *targ = new char[num+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        targ[i] = ab[rand() % 36];
    }
    targ[num] = '\0';
    return targ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make two changes. First, make the internal source array static:

```
static const char ab[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Note that this version does not specify the array size; the compiler will figure it out from the initializer.

Second, pass in a pointer to the target array:

```
void randomGet(char* targ, int num) {
    static const char ab[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIGKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i)
        targ[i] = ab[rand() % (sizeof ab - 1)];
    targ[num - 1] = '\0';
}
```

This way, the caller decides how to allocate memory for the string.